# neo4j cypher joining 2 nodes merge

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 node tags: User, Tag.

Lets say that I have a user node that exists.

Is it possible to match that node, 
and then if the tag exists merge between them,
and if the tag doesn't exist create the tag.

I tryed:

```
MATCH (n:User {name: "user"}) MERGE (n)-[r:follow]->(tag:Tag {name: "notexist")
```

In the above example it creates the node "notexist" and the relationship.
But if I have a node that is named "notexist" it doesn't merge, instead it creates another tag
named "notexist"

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lee,

Here's how to do this.

```
MATCH(n:User {name: 'user'})
WITH n
MERGE (t:Tag {name: 'notexist'})
WITH n, t
MERGE (n)-[r:follow]->(t);
```

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: this works with a second match as well, like a join:


    MATCH (t:Org)
    WITH t
    MATCH (p:User {Org: t.Id } )
    WITH t, p
    MERGE (t)-[r:WORKS_AT]->(p);